# How to create UITableViewCell that doesn't take any space?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableview that displays some prices from the net. Sometimes some prices have value "noPrice".
If i detect that price in cellForRowAtIndexPath, i return cell with no text. That takes space so the table has prices and then some spaces, prices again, spaces, etc.

What do i have to return in cellForRowAtIndexPath so the cell with no prices won't display and there will be no empty space?

Comment: Have you tried returning nil?.... never mind:  "An assertion is raised if you return nil."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should "clean up" the array before reloading the tableView data. I.e.: you receive the data from the net, you remove all "empty" values from the array, then you set the array property for the tableView and call reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfgang has the right answer in my mind - doing this *before* you display your table's probably the right idea.

But, another approach could be to use table row animation to actively remove the table rows from the table  So, before the price is known you have "--" or some other filler text - then once you know the price as "unknown",

```
// Assume you just found out that cell #2 is no good
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];

[tableView beginUpdates];
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[tableView endUpdates];
```